# Routing halts validations' client-side processes. How can I solve this?

Tags: asp.net, validation, routes

I have a trouble with ASP.NET validations. At first my validation worked successfully. But when I began routing, my client-side validations stopped working.

My problem is it deals with braces.

There is successful and unsuccessfull codes:

**Successful example**

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.Add("Pages", new Route("{PageName}/", new PageRouteHandler("~/Page.aspx")));
}
```

**Unsuccessful example**

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.Add("Pages", new Route("PageName/", new PageRouteHandler("~/Page.aspx")));
}
```

How can I overcome this problem?